# Wpf, doubleanimation on fontstretch property

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, stretch, doubleanimation

How to make an animation which changes FontStretch? This is what I've tried:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="TextBlockStyle">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
      <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontStretch" To="UltraCondensed" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
```

Comment: FontStretch is not a double. Perhaps write a [custom animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/custom-animations-overview).

Comment: Or use a [Key-Frame animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/key-frame-animations-overview).